# Classic ASP multiple checkbox click redirect to same page with value

Tags: asp-classic

I am doing some search based on check box value. If I select one checkbox I need to one value if I select second checkbox also need 2 checkbox values.

Currently I have code with radio buttons.Need to convert them to checkboxes with multiple selections. Based on request value, it will pass to a stored procedure.

```
<% if request("view")="Key CIA Initiative" then %>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" 
   onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view=Key CIA Initiative'" />
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view=High'" />
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp'" />

<% else %>

<% if request("view")="High" then %>
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view=Key            
 Initiative'" />
<input type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?
view=High'" /> 
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp'" />
<% else %>
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view=Key CIA 
Initiative'" />
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view=High'" />
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp'" /> 
<%end if%>
<%end if%>
```

When the radio buttons are clicked, it redirects to same page with request value ,then I am passing to the stored procedure

```
 If request("view")="Key CIA Initiative" Then
  strSQL = "Exec sp_get_Project_list 'Key CIA Initiative' "
 Else
 If  request("view")= "High" then
  strSQL="Exec sp_get_Project_list 'High' "
 Else 
  strSQL="Exec sp_get_Project_list "
 end if
 end if
```

Comment: Please paste the checkbox code snippet, so it's possible for someone to reference actual html or script.  What matters in particular are the checkbox names and ids.

Comment: <% if request("view1")="Key CIA Initiative" then %>
<input type="radio"  checked="checked" onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view1=Key CIA Initiative'" /><label style="width:160px">Show Key Initiative Projects</label>
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp?view2=High'" /><label style="width:160px">Show High Priority Projects</label>
<input type="radio"  onclick="javascript:document.location='Index.asp'" /><label style="width:160px">Show All Projects</label>

Comment: I am not able format the code,so didnt post the code. If my request of radio is "1" ,then i am putting up radio buttons with selected value as "checked" and onclick of radio redirecting to same page passing the querystring value

Comment: Right now the way that code reads is that checking a radio button triggers a javascript event, which appears in turn to refresh the page.  If you're intending to check multiple items, you'll have to trigger the call to the SP on some event other than clicking the checkbox/button.  I'm presuming that the radio buttons are grouped within the 'form'.  What button or link do you have that you click on once all the desired boxes are checked?

Comment: right now I have 3 radio buttons(values are High,Key Initiative and All).I am able to send each value and then retriving by sending the value to database and show the search results However now I want to add checkbox instead of radio. So user should be able to select both (High and Key Initiative values ) and need to display the result in same search page.I am not able to make the 2 checkboxes selected at the same time .Not able to capture both values

Comment: If request("view1")="Key CIA Initiative" Then
      strSQL = "Exec sp_get_Project_list 'Key CIA Initiative' "
    Else
 If  request("view2")= "High" then
      strSQL="Exec sp_get_Project_list 'High' "
    Else
 'If  Request("view")="High,Key CIA Initiative" then
 If request("view1")="High" and request("view2")="Key CIA Initiative" then
      strSQL="Exec sp_get_Project_list 'High,Key CIA Initiative' "
    Else 
      strSQL="Exec sp_get_Project_list "
end if
end if
end if

Comment: input type="checkbox".  However, you have onClick events within the buttons.  You will need to have a separate button or link that processes the submit request, otherwise you're going to trigger the response the instant you click the checkbox.

Comment: I made the input type=checkbox and onclick I could fetch single values ,but not multiple values. I cannot put submit button ,it should search though only selected checkbox value. I some how need to pass the value through onclick by passing multiple values .

Comment: please edit your post to add the code in your comments.

Comment: I have edited my question and added code,Please respond!!

Comment: if your `request(view)` has both "Key CIA Initiative"  and "high", how are you going to call the sp ? pass both the values to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
<%
Response.write "Request(view)="& request("view") & "<br />"
'Now, if request("view") has nultiple values, How are you going to call the sp? 
'pass both values to it?
If Trim(Request("view"))<>"" Then

    If InStr(Request("view"),"All")<>0 Then
        strSQL="Exec sp_get_Project_list"
    Else
    strSQL = "Exec sp_get_Project_list '"& Request("view") &"'"
    End if
Response.write "strSQL ="& strSQL & "<br />"
End If
%>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="view" value="Key CIA Initiative" <% if InStr(request("view"),"Key CIA Initiative")>0 then %> checked="checked"<%End If%> />Key CIA Initiative <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="view" value="High" <%if InStr(request("view"),"High")>0 then %> checked="checked"<%End If%>  />High<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="view" value="All" <%if InStr(request("view"),"All")>0 then %> checked="checked"<%End If%> />All <br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for help.Can this be possible with out having submit button ??

Comment: will be hard. because if you do it using onclick, the page will refresh (or submit) on each click..